# Requesting a JSON 1000 times every second. Is it expensive?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Pseucode:

```
function getjson() {
   $.getJSON('link_in_my_server_unique_for_each_user_json', function(data) {
     if (data.variable) {
        do_something();
     }
   });​ 
}

setInterval(getjson(), every_second)
```

Is it expensive to have 1000 users retrieving json file in my server every second and check if that file has some variable?

Comment: you have to ask yourself some questions :
is it a local network query ?
is this json generated by a script ?
if yes, is this script light or not ?
is it using a database ?
is the query easily cached ?

Comment: You need [`memcached`](http://memcached.org/); [`phpmemcached`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php)

Comment: There's probably some other (and better) solution to your problem. Maybe ask a question about that other problem instead of this one?

Comment: is it a static file or is it a resource dinamycally generated with a server side script and maybe after a database query? In the second case you should seriously think to some kind of server side caching

Comment: If it is one variable, what about a text file on the server with just the var? that way very little processing and it is very easy to overwrite....

Comment: Yes. It will kill your server.

Comment: @beauchette: It doesn't matter actually, all I ask if it's expensive to retrieve json from the server every second when I have let's say 1000 users (all of them are retrieving a different file). It doesn't matter, because that file is easily generated, yes, using database, but only once every few minutes, so it's cheap.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan: Thanks for your comment. Please see my comment under beauchette's answer.

Comment: so it merely depends on server bandwidth and computation capability. Just be sure to serve the smallest file possible and activate at least the gzip/deflate compression

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan: Maybe some specific approximate numbers possible to tell?

Comment: How big, in KB is your json file?

Comment: maybe you are not thinking about the real problematic. why you need periodic call? then ask you again why you need this 5 more times descending into the real issue.

Comment: Can't you just stream the file?

Comment: i would change the url to "link_in_my_server_unique_for_each_user_json_variablename.json" so only 1 or 2 bytes has to be sent, then you can handle high loads as 1000 request per second.

Comment: Just remind that the server is not only problem. You are using JavaScript, that means you are using the client's browser to do the requests and processing which may slowdown or hang the computer depending on the code and other opened programs.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL - it's true, but this is a distributed load and 1 request/second shouldn't have performance repercussions for most machines. Especially because `do something` only occurs if there is a change (infrequent) so it's just the request and response

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, you don't need to guess.  You can **measure**.

1. Use the developer tools that are available for your browser (Firebug for Firefox, Developer Tools for Chrome, etc.) and watch the requests and see how long each one takes.
2. Observe the load on your server.  If it is anything other than 0%, you're never going to see 1000 sessions running simultaneously.
3. Repeat the steps above, but with a bunch of browsers open.  It should be easy to get 20 browser windows open and running.
4. Remember that, as the server load gets past 50% your performance will become increasingly non-linear.  Once your system is blocking/thrashing a lot you can't expect to gainfully add any more clients.

Once you have a baseline measurement, you can think about optimization -- do you need it and how big a problem do you have on your hands?  Some of the usual solutions:

1. If at all possible, serve a static file or a piece of data from your APC cache.
2. If your data is cacheable but you have multiple web servers, consider a solution like memcached, MongoDB, or some other centralized very-fast key-based retrieval system.
3. If the data is dynamically retrieved from a database, consider using persistent database connections.
4. If the CPU load is high per request, you probably have something expensive in your code path.  Try to optimize the code path for that particular request, even if you have to hand-craft a special controller for it and bypass your usual framework.
5. If the network latency is high per request, use HTTP headers to try and convince the client and server to keep the connection open.

Finally, if the performance you want seems very out of reach, you'll need to consider an architectural change.  Using WebSockets would likely be a very different code path, but could conceivably result in far better performance.  I'd have to know more about what you're doing with `link_in_my_server_unique_for_each_user_json`.

Comment: In short, per 24hrs: (((amount_of_data_in_something*3600)*24)*days_in_a_month)*hosts'_something_traffic_rate

Answer (score 8):

Chances are that yes, this'll kill your average shared hosting or small VPS.

It's entirely possible to offload most of this to a system like CloudFlare or AWS CloudFront with a short (~1 second) cache expiration. Most users would get it directly from the cache, saving your server most of the work.

Comment: @creejayoz: Could you provide me with an example if possible? Thank you.

Comment: and plus, how much would it cost?

Comment: CloudFlare is free. CloudFront bills per request and per GB of bandwidth.

Comment: What about a simple example how would I use it with PHP if you have some time? Just pseudocode would be enough. Thank you.

Comment: @hakre There's no need to change "it's" to "it is" in my answer, thanks, and your line about tracking is incorrect - it's entirely possible to track via CDN with logs like CloudFront provides.

Comment: @ceejayoz: But not in near realtime. I think OP is asking (not really, you know the deal) about that, so I was adding that information. If you go CDN, you do not track users yourself, the CDN does. You can not incorporate information inside the resources that is user-based on a CDN unless you run the CDN your own (not outlined in your answer).

Comment: You can, actually, at least with CloudFront. These days it supports different caches based on cookies, query string parameters, etc., so you can serve totally different content to different user subsets if you feel like it.

Comment: @ceejayoz: I'm not talking about caching, I'm talking about requests that by their nature are not cacheable.

Answer (score 6):

If you can't cache, perhaps consider the COMET pattern, so you'd have 1,000 long-held calls rather than 1,000 calls a second, overall servicing less traffic but delivering the desired result. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29

Comment: @hey So don't use PHP for the COMET part.

Comment: @ceejayoz: What are your suggestion instead of PHP? NodeJS?

Comment: Anything that supports long polling will do. If you know Node, go for it.

Answer (score 2):

Did you think about a [web socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)

It's kind of the same principal Stack Overflow uses. You can push data to the user when the variable actually changes. But your server needs to be setup correctly to do so.

Answer (score 1):

So we are talking about at least 1k requests per second. That is already considered a fairly high load even for powerful machines. So what has to be done for each request?

- Connection initialization
- Processing request
- Executing server side logic

With this scenario you are pretty much consuming all the resources available (including file i/o). Also you are consuming most of the web server resources for some addition value that is probably not your up most feature.

**What would be a better approach?**

You want to react to a change, instead of polling for it. So for each user we would have a *channel* that contains its events and when an event occurs we want the server to notify us. Unfortunately as mentioned in another answer, this is not PHPs strongest suit.

For client side you can look at [SockJS](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client) and pair it with either [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) or [Vert.x](http://vertx.io/). You get all the architecture needed for free and it is not very hard to set up. SockJS also comes with a nice set of protocol tests, so it´s quite easy to have your own server side implementation.

With these changes you will only have one request per user to the SockJS provider and you can scale it independently if needed. Also primary service is not interrupted by JSON calls. So we end up with

- One request per page load to the SockJS provider
- One request from PHP to the SockJS provider per change

It does make authentication a bit trickier, but you can have a private key known by both PHP application and SockJS provider and use it to sign some cookie. Then you can pass that cookie with your JSON request.

Comment: I was under the impression he is serving static content (as in a JSON file prepared by some process, and then served statically).

Comment: Why should you poll it, if it's static? Makes no sense.

Comment: If it is updated every few minutes by a [non-web] process, the file is considered static if requested like 100000 times per second.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the variable is unique and relevant to the specific user, i would suggest one of these solutions:

- Cache it using a Cloud Service
- Push it to the user using Web Socket Connection
- Off load the work to the client using javascript
- Use long polling instead of interval polling

The age of polling for data is all but over, and there is often a better and more cost effective solution.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the JSON file is a "static" request (webserver directly serves the file as-is, without passing the request to some php/ruby/java/etc. process) you can determine wether your server can take it by simply benchmarking it.

This looks like a pre-cache to me (information which is to be requested is prepared by the server in advance and cached in the form of a structured response). Try using nginx for these types of requests. It also has optional modules for pre-gzipping ur files (it will automatically renew the gzip cache if you change the original file). This will give you additional CPU (and obviously more bandwidth).

Since you did not specify your file size, available bandwidth, CPU type, memory, etc., nobody can give you a yes/no answer for "Is it expensive?". It could be insignificant on a robust server with enough bandwidth (relative to your file size), or it could kill a sharedhosting or weak vps setup.

**Update:** If you set the expiration headers properly with a long Keep-alive (persistent HTTP TCP connection), you can benefit from HTTP response code 304 Not Modified (aka the server will only serve this status and some headers, and not the whole file all over again). Scripts will not be involved, serving the file will not be involved (unless it changes), TCP reconnection will not happen, disk reads will not happen (file stats are cached at least by the OS) - nginx might be the best bet for raw performance for static file checks/reads/serving.

Comment: File's size a few KB at most. Simple VPS hosting.

Comment: This is what I am talking about: http://blog.killtheradio.net/technology/using-gzip_static-in-nginx-to-cache-gzip-files/ . It will save you a lot of bandwidth without using additional CPU power. You can't squeeze any more than this out of your VPS (maybe, just maybe, if you also use a ramdisk for these "cache" files). You can create a ramdisk easily both on Windows and Linux. Further, you really have to benchmark this setup yourself (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html).

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan: Please check the link.

Answer (score 0):

How about you don't check if the file has some variable and instead your tell you tell your front end that a variable has been created? Observer pattern at work!

There exists a few libraries that can do PHPWebSocket type stuff. They usually involve some long polling type strategy.

Check out: http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/

Answer (score 0):

This really looks like you're solving the wrong problem.

I'd question why you feel the need to have every single browser hit your site every single second they are viewing it.  Maybe some context would help.

Now, if you truly need that capability then yes you can do it.  However, it's all about cost.  You'll need to talk to test it to determine exactly how many web servers you need in a load balanced configuration.  Then go back to whoever came up with the requirements and let them know the costs associated with that "feature".